# VB.NET listview not showing all data from dataset

Tags: database, vb.net, listview, datatable, dataset

This issue is driving me mad, I can't work out why it's happening. I'm running a query in an access db using vb.net then putting the data into a listview. Code:

```
    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    Dim strAccessConn As String = "Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source = T:\mydb.accdb"
    Dim cn As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection(strAccessConn)
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    Dim dt As DataTable

    'Note the query is entered as a string.
    Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter("Q_LIST", cn) 'is the name of the query in Access 

    'Set the CommandType of the SelectCommand to TableDirect
    da.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.TableDirect
    da.Fill(ds, "mytable")
    dt = ds.Tables("mytable")

    ListViewBatchResults.MultiSelect = True
    ListViewBatchResults.View = View.Details
    ListViewBatchResults.GridLines = True
    ListViewBatchResults.Columns.Clear()
    ListViewBatchResults.Items.Clear()

    For Each col As DataColumn In dt.Columns()
        ListViewBatchResults.Columns.Add(col.ToString)
    Next

    MsgBox(dt.Rows.Count)

    For Each row As DataRow In dt.Rows()

        Dim lst As ListViewItem

        lst = ListViewBatchResults.Items.Add(row(0))

        For i As Integer = 1 To dt.Columns.Count - 1
            lst.SubItems.Add(row(i))
        Next

    Next


End Sub
```

This listview is not showing all the returned data though, and I can't work out why - it works on other queries in the DB but not this one for some reason. The row count shows that there are 264 rows, the listview only shows 3 of them when I run the project however. What the heck is going on?

Cheers!

Comment: It is not possible to help you with the information you provide: if dt is populated correctly, you shouldn't find any problem and thus the problem lies in dt. Provide the query you are using or the information in dt (Rows.Count might be high but most of the rows might be empty).

Comment: I've played with it more and used another query:

SELECT TESTS.*
FROM TESTS;

This returns 95 rows non of which are blank - the listview only displays about 10 of them however. I'm starting to think this is a bug with VB?

Comment: Before starting to think such a thing, give it a shot to the option "most likely there is a bug in your program/DB" :) . Let's do a step-by-step analysis before jumping to so radical conclusions, don't you think? dt.Rows is treated as a (enumerable) Collection and I haven't ever (but ever, ever...) heard about a bug in the for each loop iterating through a Collection. First thing make sure that the iterations are right. Set a break point in lst.SubItems.Add(row(i)) and see if the values are right

Comment: also there are quite a few things which I don't understand in your code: you are populating lst but including the columns to ListViewBatchResults? Also what are you exactly intending to do with lst = ListViewBatchResults.Items.Add(row(0))?... See before going value by value, wouldn't you mind to explain the list you want to populate?

Comment: ok, commenting out the following:

            'For i As Integer = 1 To dt.Columns.Count - 1
            'lst.SubItems.Add(row(i))
            'MsgBox(i)
            'Next

Allows the first column to be populated with data from the database... so yes it's crappy coding :)

Comment: As said, let's better do things step by step to see where the problem is: you have confirmed that the dt is getting some values in. Now try this code to confirm that the columns/rows are iterated rightly: http://paste.ubuntu.com/5965875/

Comment: Yep, rows are being iterated correctly - the data is displaying as expected in the msgbox - I just need to now populate this into the listview?

Comment: Exactly. The problem you have now is that you have got 2 dimensions (columns and rows) and the list has just one. What do you want to do now? How are you expecting your data to be displayed?

Comment: OK, still the same problem - it's going through and showing the data for each row and column in the dataset but it's exiting after it gets to about 10 rows - it's not looping through all the rows in the table, but the count shows there are 95 rows! argh! :(

Comment: I need the listview to have the same number of columns as the datatable - 8?

Comment: Sorry, my bad, forgot that it was a listview. You can feed it as datasource or do it row by row. Shall I go ahead and write an answer with the possible scenarios? But before that, please, confirm that the data is being displayed rightly via MsgBoxes

Comment: Data is being displayed in msgboxs, but only up to 17 rows then it just exits. If I do the following:

        For Each row As DataRow In dt.Rows()

            ListViewBatchResults.Items.Add(row(3))

        Next

It will populate the first column in the listview with the 4th column of data from the database - which is getting closer to what I require.

Comment: You focus on making sure that all the data you want is right and can write down a code to populate the listView without any problem. Why it exits in row 17? Put a break point there and understand why this happens.

Comment: So 'For Each row As DataRow In dt.Rows()' - MsgBox(row(3)) this shows each row of data in COLUMN 4 of the query which is correct. ListViewBatchResults.Items.Add(row(3)) adds this data to the first column in the list view. How would I add this to column 3 of the list view?

Comment: Ah i'm starting to see what's going on here blank fields in the database don't show in the list view, as soon as a blank field in the DB is found it seems to EXIT and not populate the rest of the data - I need it to populate listview with blanks as well!

Comment: There shouldn't be a problem with that. Just confirm that your data is right and is iterated correctly and will write an answer to feed this data into the listview.

Comment: No - it's exiting the loop as soon as it encounters a blank field in the data table and not populating the rest of the listview. How can I stop it from doing that?

Comment: Data is right, it just exits as soon as it finds a blank field. Can you show me example code?

Comment: Give me some minutes. I am completing something else and, additionally, I will try to come up with a clear-enough approach for you to avoid any future misunderstanding.

Comment: I think the original code did actually function as it was meant to - the problem arises as soon as the loop encountered a blank field in the datatable - it exited and never finished populating the listview. I basically need some code which says "continue populating the viewview if you encounter a blank field in the datatable".

Comment: Well.. then I guess that you don't need my help. In any case, I am still not sure how a code can work when you are defining the columns in a listview and populating a different one.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim lst As ListViewItem
```

to

```
Dim lst As New ListViewItem
```